# how to show button of one form below another form if they are on the same page

Tags: html, css

These are the two form in same page

*HTML*

```
<form>
  <input type="text" name="text"><br>
  <input type = "submit" class="btn btn-primary">
</form><br>

<form>
  <input type="email" name="email"><br>
  <input type = "submit" class="btn btn-default">
</form>
```

I want btn-primary below second form (containing btn-default).

Comment: you need class name btn-primary into second form ??

Comment: @Yankie : What Happened ? My Answer Didn't Helped You. ?

Comment: ya thanx @NanaPartykar it work fine and sorry for the delay.. i didn't tried it... some problem with my internet provider..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to **HTML5**, You can use `form id` in input. The `form` attribute specifies one or more forms the  element belongs to. For more info, please have a look [Input Attributes - HTML5](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_form.asp)

> **form id** -> Specifies the form element the `<input>` element belongs to.
>   The value of this attribute must be the id attribute of a `<form>`
>   element in the same document.

*So here*, **What you can do is** :  Give `id` as `form1` (or, whatever id you want). And, declare `form="form1"` in `<input type='submit'..>` like below.

```
<form id="form1">
  <input type="text" name="text"> <br>
</form>

<br>

<form>
  <input type="email" name="email"><br>
  <input type = "submit" class="btn btn-default">
</form>

<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" form="form1">
```

Answer (score 0):

`display:flex` can do the trick here.

Give parent element `display:flex` and `flex-direction: column;`. Here i given to `body` as no other parent element.

And `order:2` to first form element. It will change first form element order second. So, it will display below.

```
body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
form:first-child {
    order: 2;
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o3kL7aj6/)**

Answer (score 0):

Set their positions as absolute and then use z-index to determine which is over which.

```
.positioned-divs { position:absolute; }
.positioned-divs.div-under { z-index:1; }
.positioned-divs.div-over { z-index:2; }
```

should work.

You'll need to set left/right and top/bottom positions too but hopefully you get the idea.

Comment: You miss understood the question